# is there any way to reverse the string without using conditional statement?

Tags: python

### Question

Write a program that receives a number on the input and prints values from 1 to that number subjected to the conditions below. 
It also should receive another boolean value 'rev' on the input.

For every number in the given range,
- If the number is a multiple of 3, or it contains digit 3, it prints "Jugs".
- If the number is a multiple of 5, or it contains digit 5, it prints "Mugs".
- If the number is a multiple of 7, or it contains digit 7, it prints "Pugs".

- If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, it prints "JugsMugs".

  - also if number contains 3 and 5, it prints "JugsMugs"
- If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 7, it prints "JugsPugs".

  - also if number contains 3 and 7, it prints "JugsPugs"
  - If the number is a multiple of 3, 5 and 7, it prints "JugsMugsPugs".

    - also if number contains 3, 5 and 7, it prints "JugsMugsPugs"

Otherwise, it prints the number.

REVERSE REQUIREMENT:
If the boolean 'rev' is True, then reverse the order of printing.
  - "PugsJugsMugs" for multiples of 3, 5 and 7
  - "PugsMugs" for multiple of 3 and 7
  - "MugsJugs" for multiple of 3 and 5
  - "PugsJugs" for multiple of 5 and 7

### What i have done

Firstly, i got an input "rev" to indicate if reversal has to done. if rev is true, then reverse the string else do not.

i have previously done this using "if" statements but here, only one or no conditional statement must be used. i have no idea to how it can be done. could someone help me out

the "else" is working fine. can someone help me with "if" part

```
num = int(input())
rev = int(input())
for i in range(1,num+1):
  *if rev:
    string = 'jugs' * bool(i%3==0 or '3' in str(i) or i)
    string = 'mugs'+ string * bool(i%5==0 or '5' in str(i) or i)
    string = 'pugs'+ string * bool(i%5==0 or '5' in str(i) or i)
    print(string or i)*

  else:  
    print("jugs"*(i%3==0 or '3' in str(i)) + "mugs"* (i%5==0 or '5' in str(i)) + "pugs"*(i%7==0 or '7' in str(i)) or i)
```

### Expected Output if rev = true or 1

```
1
2
Jugs
4
Mugs
Jugs
Pugs
8
Jugs
Mugs
11
Jugs
Jugs
Pugs
MugsJugs
```

Comment: Just think through whether you're doing things in the correct order or not.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh in the sense?

Comment: in the sense that, isn't it easier to "Reverse" a string after it's already been constructed, rather than checking first and then constructing the string again?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh can you help me with a code?

Comment: i could, but you might not gain much from it. My hint to you would be, can you "construct" the string first instead of just printing it? forget `reverse` for a sec.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh i tried..i still could not get it

Comment: If I read the assignment right, you are allowed to construct normal and reverse string even if only one is needed. You then need an expression to print the right only (similar to the expressions you use already).

Answer (score 1):

There are three main issues preventing your code from working as is.

First, in your boolean expressions `bool(i%3==0 or '3' in str(i) or i)`, the `or i` is always true since `i` is always non-zero. This means that no matter what, when you reverse the string it will print out all three values together. Getting rid of the `or i` part of the expression will fix this.

Second, you're intent seems to be to construct the strings in reverse by adding the next part to the beginning of the string. However, when you write,

```
string = 'mugs'+ string * bool(i%5==0 or '5' in str(i) or i)
```

that order gets mixed up. Instead of adding 'mugs' to the beginning of the string if it meets the conditions, you are redefining the string to equal 'mugs' and adding on the previous values if it meets the condition for mugs. Instead, simply move the `+ string` to the end of the expression to fix this ordering.

Finally, a small typo. You check for `i%5==0 or '5' in str(i)` twice, instead of checking for 7. replacing the second instance with a 7 is an easy fix. Doing these things will end up with:

```
num = int(input())
rev = int(input())
for i in range(1,num+1):
  if rev:
    string = 'jugs' * bool(i%3==0 or '3' in str(i))
    string = 'mugs' * bool(i%5==0 or '5' in str(i)) + string
    string = 'pugs' * bool(i%7==0 or '7' in str(i)) + string
    print(string or i)

  else:
    print("jugs"*(i%3==0 or '3' in str(i)) + "mugs"* (i%5==0 or '5' in str(i)) + "pugs"*(i%7==0 or '7' in str(i)) or i)
```

However, as others have pointed out, constructing the output before reversing it is more efficient, and can even get rid of the final if statement. For example:

```py
num = int(input())
rev = int(input())
for i in range(1,num+1):
    string = []
    string.append('Jugs' * bool(i % 3 == 0 or '3' in str(i)))
    string.append('Mugs' * bool(i % 5 == 0 or '5' in str(i)))
    string.append('Pugs' * bool(i % 7 == 0 or '7' in str(i)))
    print(''.join(string[::int(not rev) or -1]) or i)
```

Here I create the string as a list of values instead of an actual string so I can reverse the order of the words instead of the individual characters. Then, if `rev` is true, I join the words in reverse order, and if it's false, I join them in the normal order.